# SQL - SELECT a column that compares multiple rows of the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to analyze unique patterns from my query and show if the pattern appears in another column.

Eg.

From my query I get:

```
----------
| Date | Value|
----------
|  1   |  0.8 |
----------
|  2   |  0.2 |
----------
|  3   |  0.4 |
----------
|  4   |  0.6 |
----------
|  5   |  0.3 |
```

I want to check if there are 3 points that are ascending/descending and get a result like:

```
----------
| Date | Value| Ascending |
----------
|  1   |  0.8 |     0     |
----------
|  2   |  0.2 |     1     |
----------
|  3   |  0.4 |     1     |
----------
|  4   |  0.6 |     1     |
----------
|  5   |  0.3 |     0     |
```

The ascending column is just a bit and all values that form that pattern become true.

Any ideas?

Comment: this would be a LAG function in Oracle

Comment: Why is record "4" labeled as "Ascending = 1"?

Comment: the sequence that forms an ascending pattern in this case is 0.2, 0.4, 0.6. I am actually trying to look for ascending sequences of 5 but to simplify the problem I only put 3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code is not a complete answer.  It only compares two numbers, one to the next.

You need to compare to the next value.  Assuming the "date" column is really numeric and ascending with no holes (as you suggest in the question), then following should work in both databases:

```
select t.*,
       (case when tnext.value > t.value then 1 else 0 end) as "ascending"
from t left outer join
     t tnext
     on t."date" = tnext."date" - 1;
```

If you want to compare 3 rows, it requires more explanation.  No definitions that I can think of apply to your results.

EDIT:

Hmmm, you seem to want to find ascending sequences, and to mark the ones that have at least three rows.  If so, this is a bit harder.  The following enumerates sequences using the following technique.  It identifies the beginning of a sequence, and then it counts the number of beginnings up to each value.

To identify the beginning of an ascending sequence, look for pairs where the value goes *down*:

```
select t.*,
       (select 1
        from t tprev
        where tprev."date" = t."date" - 1 and
              tprev.value >= t.value
      ) as IsAscStart
from t;
```

To give each sequence its own id:

```
select t.*
       (select count(*)
        from t t1 join
             t tprev
             on tprev."date" = t1."date" - 1 and
                tprev.value > t1.value
        where t1."date" <= t."date"
       ) as AscGrouping
from t;
```

The challenge from this point is then getting the lengths of the sequences.  The approach to this varies widely between SQL Server and MySQL, so I can't think of an easy, database-independent way of doing that.

EDIT II:

In SQL Server, you can do what you want as:

```
with cte as (
    select t.*
           (select count(*)
            from t t1 join
                 t tprev
                 on tprev."date" = t1."date" - 1 and
                    tprev.value > t1.value
            where t1."date" <= t."date"
           ) as AscGrouping
    from t
   )
select t."date", t.value,
       (case when seqlen >= 3 then 1 else 0 end) as "Ascending"
from (select cte.*, count(*) over (partition by AscGrouping) as seqlen
      from cte
     ) t
```

Comment: This is a good one. But gives `0` for `date = 4` instead of `1` as in OP's desired output.

Comment: Do you have an idea as to how you could vary the length of the sequence in SQL Server?

Comment: Thanks for the help Gordon. One thing confusing me is, which column are you referring to when you say "t1.id <= t.id" Because there is no "id" column

Comment: @user2755428 . . . I meant the date column.

Comment: This solution is great. Just as a note for other people that maybe looking at this solution, I think you meant to write "tprev.value > t1.value" instead of 
"tprev.value > t.value", right?